# Writing a function to extract integers from strings using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Trying to Write function integers_in_brackets that finds from a given string all integers that are enclosed in brackets.

Example run: `integers_in_brackets("  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]xxx")` returns `[12, -43, 12]`. So there can be whitespace between the number and the brackets, but no other character besides those that make up the integer.

My progress so far was:

```
def integers_in_brackets(s):
    r= []
    patt = re.compile(r'\W\s*(-?\d+)')
    for i in patt.findall(s):
        r.append(int(i))
    return r
```

Yet i seem to fail in TMC where I only achieve 66% of the required

```
Failed: test.test_integers_in_brackets.IntegersInBrackets.test_second
        Lists differ: [128, 47, -43, 12] != [47, 12]

First differing element 0:
128
47

First list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 2:
-43

- [128, 47, -43, 12]
+ [47, 12] : Incorrect result for string   afd [128+] [47 ] [a34]  [ +-43 ]tt [+12]xxx!

Test results: 2/3 tests passed
 66%[????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????]
```

Comment: The Movie Channel has coding exercises?

Comment: TMC stands for Test My Code it's a learning platform by the University of Helsinki
Here is a link: https://tmc.mooc.fi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re
pat=r"(?:\[(\s*?[-+]?\d+\s*?)\])"
list(map(eval, re.findall(pat, "  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]")))                                                                                                        
#[12, -43, 12]
```

Comment: This is a great concept yet it fails when facing multiple spaces before an int

example: s = `"   afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [        -43 ]tt [+12]xxx!"`

Comment: If you are kind enough could you point out what the " : " indicates as well as the first and last escape rules what are they escaping

Comment: I created: https://regex101.com/r/7Oe2a6/1  if you want to try it, if you have an example it doesn't work i can modify it

Comment: that works like a charm but could you please elaborate what is a non capturing group aka " (?:) "

Comment: When you use (?:) it means that the group is matched but is not captured for back-referencing i.e non-capturing group. It's not stored in memory to be referenced later on. I hope that helps

Comment: so this is just for memory efficiency and not referencing it as \1 but it doesn't contribute to the output so this works too

`\[\s*([+-]?\d+)\s*\]`

Comment: Thank you for your support it's much appreciated

Comment: You don't need the lazy quantifiers or the non-capture group - you should change it to @OmarAhmed's pattern to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit brackets should work:

```
def integers_in_brackets(s):
    r= []
    patt = re.compile(r'\[\s*(\+?-?\d+)\s*\]')
    for i in patt.findall(s):
        r.append(int(i))
    return r
```

Comment: this forms a complication as there is a +-43 where it appends it to the list as +-43 which is invalid and doesn't filter out the +

If you could explain what does the first \ indicates I'd be thankfull what is it escaping

Comment: @OmarAhmed It is an escape.

Comment: For what exactly if i may ask?

Comment: @OmarAhmed `[` starts a character class in regex, but `\[` is a literal `[`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy and more straightforward way to do it:

```
re.findall(r'\[\s*([+-]?\d+)\s*\]',"  afd [asd] [12 ] [a34]  [ -43 ]tt [+12]")
```